# Issues while trying to send data to Web server

Tags: php, android, web-services, postman, isset

I need to send data to my web server and unfortunately i'm not able to do that. I've spent like hours figuring out whats wrong and didn't make anything of it.

I'm trying to login a user using my web service. Here is my php script

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $status = isset($response["status"]) ? $response["status"] : '';
        if($status == 'disabled' || $status == 'Disabled') {
            // user is disabled
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Your account has been suspended, please contact the admin";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else {
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["first_name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email_address"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["date_time"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Username or password is incorrect";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the getUserByEmailAndPassword() function in use is this:

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT _id, first_name, last_name, email, profile_picture, is_verified, phone, is_admin, gender, access_token FROM users WHERE email = ? and password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // check for password equality
            // if ($password == $user['password']) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            // }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

When a post request is made to it, this is the response i get
[image]

Even if i do provide the email and password, the issue persists. **The response specifies that no email or password was provided.**

Any sort of help/hint would really be appreciated here.

Comment: In your postman request you using a GET request, however, you're checking for a POST value in your code.

Comment: It still has the same issue when changed to POST: Connected successfully{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters email or password is missing!"} @ross wilson

Comment: @rossWilson The code which i have mentioned works perfectly fine on my local sever

Comment: Instead of $_GET or $_POST, try $_REQUEST which has both... 
`if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])) {`

now regardless of how you view the page, via POST or GET, the $_REQUEST array will have your key/value pairs.

Comment: Could you add the following underneath `$db = ...`  and then add the output to question: `die('<pre>' . json_encode($_POST) . '</pre>');`

Comment: Scratch that. I've just tested it in postman and even if you send the above as a post request the email and password values are still in the GET array. You need to click on the body tab underneath and add the values there.